# Black transparent backdrop in iOS on popup

Tags: ios, swift, transparent, uiactionsheet

I need to add black semi transparent view below popup in such a way that it covers everything on back and is removed when popup is dismissed. Just like we do in popover for iPad Or Actionsheet.

This is the image of what i want to achieve :
[image]

If you see the transparent view is above status bar and tabbar as well.

this is the code i wrote to achieve it:

```
bgView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame.size.width ,[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame.size.height)];
bgView.center = self.view.center;
bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
bgView.alpha = 0.70;
```

-(void)showDatePicker:(InvoiceDateCell *)cell WithDatePickerView:(DatePicker *)dateView{
    [self.view insertSubview:bgView belowSubview:dateView];
}

But, this doesn't covers status bar, sometimes not even nav bar.

Any pointers, how this is implemented in iOS. It is used very frequently in iOS.

Comment: try bgView.frame = self.view.bounds;

Comment: You probably have to add the view to the Application Window

Comment: then, i would have to add the popup on top of bgView ? ... need to try, but as i remember i  have tried it earlier but it didn't work....

Comment: and what would it be in swift ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in another way, you need to create a new viewController for the pop-up, in this viewController you need to set the background colour black with alpha 0.5 and also you need to create a view in the centre of this viewController as a pop-up view.

**Note:** You need to set some property of this viewController as picture show below,

[image]

Now you need to present this view controller when ever you need a pop-up, and dismiss whenever you need to hide pop-up

Comment: does it really it be a UIVewController's subclass?

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4 / Swift 5

```
let containerView = transitionContext.containerView

// Backdrop
dimmedView.backgroundColor = .black
dimmedView.alpha = 0.0
containerView.addSubview(dimmedView)
dimmedView.frame = containerView.bounds

// Back animation
self.dimmedView.alpha = 0.8
```